# Rails i18n language change spontaneously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2, rails-i18n

I m trying to use i18n with rails, but there was a mistake I did not handle.

> config/initiliazers/locale.rb

```
I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('lib', 'locale', '*.{rb,yml}')]
I18n.default_locale = :tr
```

> config/application.rb

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :tr
```

> production.rb

```
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
```

belows are methods that I configure the language

> application_controller.rb

```
def set_language
  I18n.locale = params[:lang] || I18n.locale
  redirect_to request.referrer
end
```

> sessions_controller.rb

```
def new
logger.debug "* Accept-Language: #{request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']}"
if (extract_locale_from_accept_language_header == "tr")
  I18n.locale = extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
else
  I18n.locale = "en"  
end  
logger.debug "* Locale set to '#{I18n.locale}'"
```

end

in the server, when I click a link the language changes continuously although the link is not about the language

Answer (score 0):

The post [Ruby on Rails网站语言国际化](http://my.oschina.net/huangwenwei/blog/519617) tell you how to do.

Comment: I want to find what I did wrong, not looking for a different solution.

Comment: it works on my computer both development and production, but in aws it is choosing alternately